# How to load the symfony server when logging in

Tags: linux, shell, symfony, scripting

I am using linux and every time I start the session I must put this command to start the symfony server

```
php bin/console server:start
```

Can you think of a way to automate this process?

Thank you

Comment: you can use apache config

Comment: refer this doc https://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: @Robert - not sure if linking to Symfony 2.1 documentation is really all that helpful.  Things have changed over the last 5 years or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to write a script that launch the server and place this script in `/etc/profile.d`

`/etc/profile.d/your_script.sh`

**Exemple for the script.sh**

```
cd /path/to/your/symfony/project;
php bin/console server:start
```

**More info**

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fprofile.d.2F.2A.sh

Comment: Not so useful, I think he doesn't want to launch anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this would be to get rid of the server:start command and setup a virtual host. Once you  setup a virtual host, you should be able to access the website with the url you define. Something like http://yousite.local. If you are not sure on how to create virtual hosts. The following articles helps you.

1. [How to setup virtual hosts on Apache](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)
2. [Symfony web server configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using apache and Linux there will be a folder /var/www/html/. Place your code in the folder and call the project directly from the browser as localhost/project_name/web/app_dev.php . Or as @Aleem says, set up a virtual host in your system.
Edit : On xampp, I think the folder is htdocs or something.